# Using ack to search inside files with no extensions

Tags: grep, ack

I have some text "bar" contained in files `FOO` and `foo.cc`.

Is there a way to tell `ack-grep` to search inside files with no extension (namely `FOO`)?

I've tried something like this:

```
ack-grep --type-set=foo=FOO bar
```

which returns the text in foo.cc, but not file FOO.

I've also added the --type-set to my .ackrc file, calling

```
ack-grep --help-types
```

shows that ack-grep is looking for `.FOO` files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine `ack-grep`'s `-a` (search everything) with `-G` (only search files that match a given regex). Something like:

```
ack-grep -a -G '^[^.]+$' what-to-search-for
```

should do the trick.

Under ack2 you have to define a custom type:

```
ack-grep --WANTED --type-set WANTED:match:^[^.]+$ what-to-search-for
```

works for me.

Comment: This only works for ack 1.x.  The `-a` and `-G` flags have been removed in ack 2.0 because they are no longer necessary.

Comment: @AndyLester good point, thanks. Updated for ack2. (I'd argue that ack1 is more obvious in this case, but hey.)

Answer (score 2):

My ack is of version 2.12. Bellow command should work.

```
$ ack --type-set make:is:Makefile --type=make string-pattern
```

So similarly,

```
$ ack --type-set foo:is:FOO --type=foo string-pattern
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do what you want with ack 1.x.  You need to upgrade to [ack 2.0](http://beyondgrep.com/).

ack 1.x did not have a way to deal with files without extensions.  ack 2.0 adds a much more flexible file-specification system.